# Getting started with builds for webapps

Tags: git, deployment, build, automation, lamp

I work with LAMP, git, and OSX on a small team. We build websites and webapps. I'm very interested in learning about builds, continuous integration, unit testing, minifying JS/CSS, deployments, and automation - but don't know where to start!

It feels like one of those learned-through-osmosis-things with a high barrier of entry that can only be circumvented by the luxury of a large team that "knows what it's doing already".

Where's a good place to start? I'm interested in:

- Specific Tools & Programs
- Lynda Courses/Videos/Podcasts/ect
- Books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A book well worth reading, that will outline the different processes and models important to think about is "Continuous Delivery", from the Martin Fowler Signature Series:

[Continuous Delivery - Martin Fowler signature series](http://martinfowler.com/snips/201006021426.html)

It will cover all the "theory" and is seriously enlightening, before you get bogged down with getting going with it.